# C# .NET Objects doesn't update properties correctly from method being called from derived class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have derived class in my WPF project like this

```
public class NetworkCommunicator : WindowWallet
{        
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer listenerTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    public NetworkCommunicator()
    {
        listenerTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(listenerTimer_Elapsed);
        listenerTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        listenerTimer.Start();
    }

    private void listenerTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.AddLogContent("some text");
    }
}
```

And the parent class that is also an currently opened window.

```
public partial class WindowWallet : Window
{
    NetworkCommunicator netCommunicator;
    public WindowWallet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        netCommunicator = new NetworkCommunicator();
    }
    public virtual void AddLogContent(string s)
    {
        textBoxNetworkLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + s);
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML code of the textBoxNetworkLog

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxNetworkLog" Height="153" Margin="10,0,10.4,33.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="AnoBIT Network Log started..." IsReadOnly="True" TextChanged="textBoxNetworkLog_TextChanged"/>
```

The problem is that the textBoxNetworkLog.Text property doesn't update and I can't see the changes in the opened WindowWallet. I made some debugging and I can see that the textBoxNetworkLog.Text is updating every second and the property is changing as expected in the Locals window when I debug my code step by step (every second there is new line of some text as expected). But that's only during the debugging and I see zero changes in the opened WindowWallet.
I know that

- The listenerTimer is running
- The AddLogContent executes
- When I type something in the opened WindowWallet into the textBoxNetworkLog, the textBoxNetworkLog.Text property in the Locals does not (obviously) sync with the text I typed in.
- When I try different object other than textBoxNetworkLog in the AddLogContent method, the text doesn't change in the Window aswell
- I have only one WindowWallet opened and only one instance of the NetworkCommunicator created
- I am doing this on the WPF framework
- The textBoxNetworkLog_TextChanged contains literally nothing, so there is no problem there

It just looks like the method doesn't change the text of the textBoxNetworkLog that is in the CURRENT INSTANCE of the opened Window or something like that. Please help me, I am hopeless. Thanks

EDIT: I guess it just doesn't refer to the current instance which I have opened now. I solved it with this one line (maybe there will be more in need in a case there will be more WindowWallet instances opened

```
WindowWallet CurrentInstanceWallet = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WindowWallet>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Maybe the textbox is beging updated on the wrong thread.  Try using dispatcher.begininvoke to update the text in the textbox

Comment: When you have derived class definitions, that does not mean that instances (the window you opened and the communicator) are linked

Comment: Your application design is broken. Creating a new NetworkCommunicator will involve a call of the WindowWallet constructor (because it's the base class), which will in turn create another NetworkCommunicator. You should have got a StackOverflow exception. Search the web for articles about the MVVM pattern. Then make your NetworkCommunicator a view model class and bind your UI to its properties by means of WPF data binding.

Comment: @Clemens I actually thought that base keyword will call the current instance from which it was created. It was unlogical thinking since parent class doesn't have to be the one from which it was created from and doesn't to have an existing instance at all. Fixed my mistake and learned something, you can see my answer below to find out how did I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself. This one line will do the trick.

```
WindowWallet CurrentInstanceWallet = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WindowWallet>().FirstOrDefault();
```

If there are gonna be more instances of WindowWallet's it will maybe need to modify a little bit.